# How to get value of completed task while uploading video to AWS?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

I have implemented the AWSS3 to upload the video to the AWS server and also I want to get the value of task which has been completed using `AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()` to show the value on progress bar. But I am not getting the value please see the below code atached.

///1

```
typealias progressBlock = (_ progress: Double) -> Void //2

typealias completionBlock = (_ response: Any?, _ error: Error?) -> Void //3
```

//2
// Upload video from local path url

```
func uploadVideo(videoUrl: URL, progress: progressBlock?, completion: completionBlock?) {
    print("video url is \(videoUrl)")
    let fileName = self.getUniqueFileName(fileUrl: videoUrl)
    print("keyname \(fileName)")
    self.uploadfile(fileUrl: videoUrl, fileName: fileName, contenType: "video", progress: progress, completion: completion)
}
```

//method to upload the video

```
private func uploadfile(fileUrl: URL, 
fileName: String, 
contenType: String,
 progress: progressBlock?, completion: completionBlock?) {

    // Upload progress block

    let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()

    expression.progressBlock = {(task, awsProgress) in
        guard let uploadProgress = progress else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            debugPrint("completed portion of the task is \(awsProgress.fractionCompleted)")
            uploadProgress(awsProgress.fractionCompleted)
            //progress!(awsProgress.fractionCompleted)
        }
    }
     // Completion block
    var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock?
    
    completionHandler = { (task, error) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            if error == nil {
                let url = AWSS3.default().configuration.endpoint.url
                let publicURL = url?.appendingPathComponent(self.bucketName).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
                if let completionBlock = completion {
                    completionBlock(publicURL?.absoluteString, nil)
                }
            } else {
                if let completionBlock = completion {
                    print("error is at completionBlock \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                    completionBlock(nil, error)
                }
            }
        })
    }
    
    // Start uploading using AWSS3TransferUtility
    let awsTransferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
    awsTransferUtility.uploadFile(fileUrl, bucket: bucketName, key: fileName, contentType: contenType, expression: expression, completionHandler: completionHandler).continueWith { (task) -> Any? in
        if let error = task.error {
            print("error is: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        if let url = task.result {
            // your uploadTask
            print("url is \(url)")
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Install cocoapods `pod 'AWSS3'`.

Here `filePath` is the path of the file to be uploaded.

```
func saveModelInAmazonS3() {
    let remoteName = fileName + ".mov" //extension of your file name
    let S3BucketName = "bucketName"
    let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()!
    uploadRequest.body = filePath!
    uploadRequest.key = remoteName
    uploadRequest.bucket = S3BucketName
    uploadRequest.contentType = "application/zip"
    uploadRequest.acl = .publicRead
    uploadRequest.uploadProgress = { (bytesSent, totalBytesSent, totalBytesExpectedToSend) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { // here you can track your progress
            let amountUploaded = totalBytesSent 
            let fileSize = totalBytesExpectedToSend
            print("\(amountUploaded)/\(fileSize)")
            let progress = (CGFloat(amountUploaded) / CGFloat(fileSize)))
        })
    }
    
    let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()
    transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWith(block: { (task: AWSTask) -> Any? in
        if let error = task.error {
            self.delegate.errorInUpload(uploadState: self.uploadState)

            print("Upload failed with error: (\(error.localizedDescription))")
        }
        if task.result != nil {
            let url = AWSS3.default().configuration.endpoint.url
            print("Uploaded to:\(String(describing: url))")
            
        }
        return nil
    })
    
}
```